# MySQL installed with predefined password

Tags: mysql, linux

So I'm running crunchbang linux and installed mysql-server using the following terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Setup runs without problems, but when trying to access mysql I get "Error 1045 Access denied".

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

The same goes for using root.

The tutorial I used stated that during setup of mysql-server I'd be asked to set a password, but this step never happened.

Edit: 
Completely removed everything related to mysql from my system (including configuration files), problem persists.

When trying

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

the error also occurs, although according to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html) this should grant me access if no password is set.

___Update:
Since I'm still having this problem even with my new laptop (running ubuntu 12.10 now) I'll do a quick update:

Neither

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
```

nor

```
mysql -u root

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourpassword');
```

worked. Any thoughts?

__Update 2

By stopping the service and then following [this guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix) I seem to have managed to reset the root password.

Still, using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and entering the password I've set, it still throws access denied.

Comment: what is exact error message you got?

Comment: added the full error message

Comment: somehow you are trying to login with empty user

Comment: nah, SO just didn't like me having 'username' in <...> :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay my suspicion was right: I installed mysql using the synaptic package manager and during setup this seemed to skip the step of setting a root password. I don't know why the password reset didn't work, but after installing mysql from commandline everything's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would try some variants of that command (just hit enter / empty / no password):

mysql -h localhost -u root -p

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

mysql -h $HOSTNAME -u root -p

It might simply be that mysql does not recognize you as a local user.

Comment: none of them worked, still the same error (added the error message btw).
Judging from the error message not being recognized as the local user isn't the problem

Comment: the error says "using password no". did you set a password when the mysql-server was installed? you have to use that one, not from the linux system.
I would follow the link below from tricolsan using section "C.5.4.1.3. Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions" to set a new root password.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Ubuntu/Debian you can do the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
```

Which should ask you the initial question for the initial password if I am not mistaken.

Edit:

Then according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

```
mysql -u root

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourpassword');
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try that. Also what version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: the given command also returns the access denied error. As I wrote in my question, I'm running crunchbang which is debian based.

Comment: @Rickyfox I see the error now try 'mysql -uroot' as it seems to not take root as username with a space for some reason.

Comment: nah, SO just didn't like me having 'username' in <...> :/

Comment: But it does actually say root@localhost yes?

Comment: well since I'm still having this problem, do you have any ideas?

Comment: And you have tried starting MySQL in safemode to reset the root password?

Comment: Yup, I just noticed that the reason why the safemode method doesn't work is the fact that after I kill the mysqld process, it immediatly starts again - I'll need to stop that, any advice?

Comment: This can have multiple reasons, are you sure the service started properly? `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: yeah you were right, updated again. Error persists after resetting password, and yes I've typed in the password correctly

Comment: Then I have no idea, the only thing that comes to mind is that you have two versions of mysql installed but this seems a little far fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the password by this manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html